# In textmate, how do I jump to a file? how to open the file explorer?

Tags: macos, textmate

On my macbook, when I am exploring my filesystem and then open a file in textmate, it just opens the code window.

How can I open the textmate file explorer?

How can I jump to a file that is in a "project"? i.e. that is a file within the root folder or sub folders?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution, that I personally prefer, is to:

**Assumptions:**

- Your desired folder with the project sits at:

  /Users/username/projects/example/

**Solution 1:**

1. Open a new console window or console tab.
2. Navigate inside your project folder by typing:

   cd /Users/username/projects/example/
3. Open the current folder as Textmate project with file explorer by typing:

   mate .

**Solution 2:**

1. Open a new console window or console tab.
2. Open your project within Textmate with file explorer by typing:

   mate /Users/username/projects/example/

**Explanation**

The 'mate' command starts up your Textmate editor from the command line. You can pass a path argument to the 'mate' command, which does not have to be a file, but can also be a folder. Once you pass in a folder as an argument, Textmate will open up in project mode and therefore displays a file browser window.

Comment: but what about if I just open a single file, how do I see the file explorer then?

Comment: I'm sorry, the only way I can think of, would be to open the folder first and then 'cmd + t' to quickly jump to the file.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to create a new project in `Textmate` using the `New Project` menu item (from the `File` menu) then add files and folders to the project using the buttons at the bottom of the project pane.  Save the project with the `Save Project` menu item.  You can then re-open the project later by either double-clicking on the project file in the Finder or opening inside of `Textmate`.

Comment: You can even double-click a file inside the project. This will start TextMate with the whole project one the side. Another solution, when opening files from finder, is using OpenInTextMate.App (available from http://henrik.nyh.se/2007/10/open-in-textmate-from-leopard-finder). This gives you the possibility to open TextMates project view for folders in finder by simply clicking on a symbol.